# Can I add an image path from a .txt file in a webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, html, text

I need to dynamically add in the img src full file path to a file from a .txt file. So far i have been using the below code to populate titles, and descriptions:

```
< ?php

    $myFile = "film_music/feature1.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array<br />
echo $lines[0]; //line 1

    ? >
```

The feature file contains all details for movies that will eventually be displayed here:

http://www.londonosophy.com/film_music2.php

Currently the file contains the following rows:

Sightseers (2012)
Dark comedy, featuring Alice Lowe
images/Sightseers-TinaPencil.jpg

Does anyone know php code that can read line X (or line 3 in this case) and dynamically populate the img src="" file path?

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Instead of a text file, you'd be well served by using a CSV.

Comment: What is your problem? You do not know how to iterate over file lines? Or you do not know how to check each line to check if it is a file name or not?

Comment: Hi Sanja, I don't know how to iterate over file lines, so I want to simply add in the file path image URL to my html from a .txt/ CSV file - but need PHP to know the PHP to do this, thanks

Comment: *but need to know the PHP to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to iterate over lines and need to check if line contains file path (for example, if sometimes there are white lines between blocks and sometimes they are missing), then:

```
<?php
$myFile = 'film_music/feature1.txt';
$lines = file($myFile);
$needle = 'images/';
$needleLen = strlen($needle);
foreach ($lines AS $line) {
  $line = trim($line);
  if (substr($line, 0, $needleLen) == $needle) {
    echo '<img src="' . $line . '" alt="" />';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: With this script is there a way to point to different img paths in the same file? 

E.g. I will have in a .txt file I have up to 19 img paths, so if possible I'd like to be able to pull an img path from a specific line.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch 3rd line of the file every time, because it contains that path of the image.

```
<?php
global var $raw;
$myFile = "film_music/feature1.txt";
// open file...
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array<br />
for($i=2;$i<=no_of_lines;$i+3){
    $raw = $lines[$i];
}
// Populate $raw variable where you need.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$fh = fopen(...)` and loop every line.

```
while (!feof($fh)) {
$line = fgets($fh);
  if ($line === false) {
    throw new Exception("File read error");
  }
  [do your things.]
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line of text line as:

```
$lines=file('file.txt');


    $lines=array();
    $fp=fopen('file.txt', 'r');
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $line=fgets($fp);

        //process line however you like
        $line=trim($line);

        //add to array
        $lines[]=$line;

    }
    fclose($fp);
```

if you don't need any special processing, this should do what you're looking for

```
$lines = file($lines, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

may this help you... :)

you can check all line of text file with `in_array("you want", $lines)` as you desire...if its not dynamically....

Comment: Thanks,  with this can I add in just the text of the file path? - as I don't want to dynamically add in the image but the file path which points to a different location.

Comment: see, this code revert all line of text file is as array so here you can check by array as result you want to compare and perform your willing task...